# Nginx теряет путь к статике при втором и больше путей

Tags: python, nginx, static, fastapi

Статика отдается если путь один
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но если больше то путь почему-то становится не тем и соответственно не находится
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот что пишет консоль браузера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть почему-то admin встает перед assets, и видимо ошибка в этом? Вот моя конфигурация:

```
upstream backend {

  server localhost:8000;

}


 server{
   listen 8080;

    location /assets {
    root /home/avgust/Документы/py_shit/pet_choc/pet_choc_files;
    }

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    }


}
```

У меня связка Fastapi, gunicorn, nginx. Знаю что можно статику как-то отдавать через fastapi, но у меня она тоже не работает, поэтому решил уж с нжиксом пробовать. Буду благодарен за помощь((

Comment: Приведите конфиг текстом

Comment: Хотя даже без него понятно что у вас стандартная ошибка и нужно исправлять пути к статике в ваших скриптах, что бы они начинались со слеша.

Comment: @AlexeyTen всм где именно, в нжиксе или где конкретно?

Comment: «в ваших скриптах»

Comment: /admin/assets проксируется у вас на бэкенд. Чтобы любой урл, содержащий assets отдавался nginx-ом используйте ```location ~ /assets/```

Comment: @AlekseyVaganov не помогло, все равно 404 (

Comment: @AvgustFavn рассмотрим запрос GET /admin/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js. У вас файл лежит по этому пути /home/avgust/Документы/py_shit/pet_choc/pet_choc_files/admin/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js ? И внесите пожалуйста в вопросе изменения в конфиг, при которых вы пытаетесь сделать этот запрос и рекомендованный мной конфиг не помогает